# access another dataset inside an expression

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

For each row in my report, I have one field where I need to check another dataset to determine the data that goes in there.

This is the query for that dataset:

```
        select t1.this, t2.that
        from thisTable t1
        left join thatTable t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
        where t1.someId = @param1
        and t2.someId = @param2
```

Is there a way to pass in parameters to another dataset via an expression?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

Create a Dataset and make a lookup key:

```
SELECT t1.this, t2.that, 
    CAST(t1.someId AS VARCHAR(5)) + CAST(t2.someId AS VARCHAR(5)) as LkpKey
FROM thisTable t1
LEFT JOIN thatTable t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Now in the Field Expression you can use a [LookUp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx) to get the desired value. Where `#YourIDField1` and `#YourIDField2` are the Values from the Original Dataset you wish to use as the LookUp, and `#FieldYouWant` is the value you want returned from the LookUp Dataset.

```
=LookUp(Fields!#YourIDField1.Value & Fields!#YourIDField2.Value,
    Fields!LkpKey.Value,
    Fields!#FieldYouWant.Value,
    "#YourDataSet")
```

You can wrap the LookUp in an IIF if a Default Value is desired like this:

```
=IIF(LookUp(Fields!#YourIDField1.Value & Fields!#YourIDField2.Value,
        Fields!LkpKey.Value,Fields!#FieldYouWant.Value, "#YourDataSet") <> nothing,
    LookUp(Fields!#YourIDField1.Value & Fields!#YourIDField2.Value,
        Fields!LkpKey.Value,Fields!#FieldYouWant.Value, "#YourDataSet"), 
    "Default")
```